# flex pagination example help

Tags: apache-flex, pagination

I've found a flex paging example I'd like to get working, but can't seem to get it running.

The Example files can be found here: http://blogs.adobe.com/tlf/2008/12/actionscript-pagination-exampl.html

I've downloaded and imported the project into flex. However I seem to have an error that prevents the example from running. Here is the error that appears

The definition of base class DisplayObjectContainerController was not found. – PaginationWidget.as

Method marked override must override another method. – PaginationWidget.as

Comment: If you want to offer cash, why not use one of the websites that's designed for that purpose? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_market#Internet-based_knowledge_markets

Comment: I've had great luck with Stackoverflow, I trust the people on this site and their knowledge base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved the issue.

Got a hold of someone from Adobe and turns out that the files posted contained old beta code.

He was able to direct me to the new updated source code. - http://blogs.adobe.com/tlf/files/2010/09/Pagination20Build169.zip

He informed me that they are currently slowly working on posting all their examples with current source.

Answer (score 1):

Here's things I would look at:

Did you install Flex builder in another directory?  Is it in your path?  Is it on a removable or network drive?

Do you have Flex builder OR Flash CS4  Professional with the TextLayout plugin?  Do I have the appropriate example download for my setup?

Comment: I've added a libs folder and got my hands on the paginationAS.swf but I'm still coming up with errors.

Comment: the project is in the right directory, and I'm not having any permissions issues. The textlayout.swf has been added to the project. And I've tried deleting the project and re-downloading all with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

hey, take a look at this component ..

http://forums.adobe.com/message/3166670#3166670

it may help you